# Is there a free or opensource SERM Modeling tool for linux?

Tags: linux, modeling

I looking for a good [SERM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured-Entity-Relationship-Model) Modeling tool for linux. Is there any? Which is best?

Comment: completely misread that topic at first glance. heh. no idea but this might be up your alley: http://sourceforge.net/projects/fmcstencils/

Comment: Does "free" mean gratis or libre?

Answer (score 2):

[**Open ModelSphere**](http://www.modelsphere.org/) may be the lone mature tool that fits the requirements...

- open source (under GPL)
- run on Linux: cross platform, actually, since it is Java-based.
- standard fare for typical modeling tools, including forward and backward engineering and validation.
- No *explicit* support for SERM, but ability to introduce new notations. Several of the notations readily included appear to be relatively close to [what I understand] SERM is.

This last point might be the show-stopper... hopefully this suggestion can be be a starting point.

**Disclosure**:
I'm no modeling wizard, merely an occasional user of modeling tools typically included in software development IDEs.  Also, I'm not versed in SERM in particular, and unsure of its subtle (or so subtle) differences with other modeling metamodels. 
I would typically remain an interested spectator of this type of questions, but in view of the little attention it has received so far (and in view of the +50 bounty, right!) I'm kindly posting the above with the intent of maybe stirring things a bit.  I'll be glad to delete this answer, amend it as suggested and otherwise try and help with generating traffic in this direction.
If nothing else, this answer may prompt Anton Bessonov to elaborate a bit on specific uses and capabilities would be relevant to his quest.

Comment: Hello mjv, thank you. There a lot of tools (for instance http://www.diagramming.org/) to modeling ERMs, class diagramms and so on. Most of them are extendable. But I looking for SERM out of the box because SERM is a little bit complex to extend in tool (because has restrictions, for instance all arrows must be from left to right, no cycles).

Comment: Understood.  Anton, do let me know if you'd rather I remove this reply, as a way of maybe inducing more traffic to this question.

Comment: I give you +50 because one answer is better that no answer and bounty lost anyway :)

Comment: @AntonBessonov : vielen Dank. All is not lost.